# Haskell datatype range

Tags: haskell, types

I define my own datatype.

```
data Row = A | B | C deriving (Show,Eq,Ord)
```

The question is, if there is a more elegant way to define my range than this?

```
instance Ix Row where
  range (A,A) = [A]
  range (A,B) = [A,B]
  range (A,C) = [A,B,C]
  range (B,B) = [B]
  range (B,C) = [B,C]
  range (C,C) = [C]
  range _     = []
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is: Derive `Enum` and define

```
range (x, y) = [x .. y]
```

Answer (score 11):

## By using the `Enum` instance

Yes, you can make `Row` an **instance of `Enum`**, in fact you do not have to define it yourself:

```
data Row = A | B | C deriving (Show, Eq, Ord, Enum)
```

This means that we can now use "*range notation*". For example:

```
Prelude> [A .. C]
[A,B,C]
Prelude> [A .. B]
[A,B]
Prelude> [C .. B]
[]
```

So we can now define our `Ix` instance as:

```
instance Ix Row where
    range (x, z) = [x .. z]
    index (x, _) y = fromEnum y - fromEnum x
    inRange (x, z) y = x <= y && y <= z
```

Or even without parameters:

```
instance Ix Row where
    range = uncurry enumFromTo
    -- ...
```

## By defining a custom "successor" function

In case you do not want to make it an `Enum` instance (I do not see any reason here not to, but this is of course a rather hypothetical datatype). We can construct a list by using recursion and each time calculating the successor:

```
instance Ix Row where
    range (x, z) = go x
        where go y | y > z = []
              go A = A : go B
              go B = B : go C
              go C = [C]
```

Although the code fragment above is still a large amount of work, it scales *linear* with the number of data constructors, whereas an exhaustive approach, would scale *quadratic* with the number of data constructors (*not* in time complexity, but in the amount of code).

Comment: Shouldn't that be `enumFromTo`?